# Change color of different HTML tags in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 8.0.3 and I'm trying to customize fonts/colors.

I would like to have different colors for different HTML tags (form, table, tr, etc). But in PhpStorm's editor through `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | HTML` I'm only finding a way to change all HTML tags to one color without being able to drill it down by tag.

Is this possible with PhpStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATM it's not possible .. and it's not yet planned to be implemented.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-330 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.